# Создания метода класса и передача указателя

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Приветствую всех!

Сильно не пинайте, но носом потыкать можно. В чем суть: 
Надо передать указатель файла в другой класс **(parserbinaryfile)**. Там, в классе **parserbinaryfile**, есть метод:

```
void setFile(QFile *file);
```

и он в `.срр` файле описан:

```
void parserbinaryfile::setFile(QFile *file)
{
    m_file = file;
}
```

`m_file` это: `private:
             QFile* m_file;`

Я основном классе **BackEnd**  я создаю экземпляр класса `parserbinaryfile:`

```
parserbinaryfile *parsFile{nullptr};
```

И выделяю память: `parsFile = new parserbinaryfile();`

Через экземпляр класса я передаю сам указатель на файл:

```
QFile getFileOpenToRead(openedFile);
parsFile->setFile(getFileOpenToRead);
```

Но при компиляции - выскакивает ошибка: [image: Ошибка]

Не знаю как справиться. Нужна ваша помощь.

Чуть не забыл.

`openedFile` это: `QString openedFile = dialog.getOpenFileName();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему так: (этим я отделился от основного класса и теперь у меня независимый класс)

В основном классе не надо ничего писать. Пишем в том классе, в который мы хотим что-то передать:

```
static QByteArray *parseDataBin(QByteArray* data);
```

Рефакторим в .срр этот метод

В основном классе инклудим этот класс и в нужном слоте пишем:

```
parserbinaryfile::parseDataBin(&buffArray);
```

Таким образом я передаю содержимое массива. А перед этим я в `QByteArray` всё сбросил с файла таким образом: `buffArray = getFileOpenToRead.readAll();`

Answer (score 0):

в строках

```
QFile getFileOpenToRead(openedFile);
parsFile->setFile(getFileOpenToRead);
```

Вы делаете странную вещь - передаете указатель на функцию.

как минимум нужно написать так

```
QFile f = getFileOpenToRead(openedFile);
parsFile->setFile(&f);
```

Это скопмилируется и скорее всего будет работать. Но по выходу с функции объект QFile будет уничтожен и файл будет закрыт. Соответственно то, что будет передано внутрь функции setFile будет работать в лучшем случае странно. Я бы передавал внутрь setFile просто имя файла, а уже parserbinaryfile открывал его.  Второй способ исправить - это сделать move-семантику, что бы класс parserbinaryfile стал собственником объекта QFile. Третий способ - это использовать умные указатели.

Answer (score 0):

```
parsFile->setFile(getFileOpenToRead);
```

замените на

```
parsFile->setFile(&getFileOpenToRead);
```

Ведь вы пытаетесь передать объект, а в сигнатуре функции у вас указатель. Об этом же подсказывает последняя строка на вашем скриншоте ошибки.

Помимо прочего, как указали выше:

> Но по выходу с функции объект QFile будет уничтожен и файл будет закрыт. Соответственно то, что будет передано внутрь функции setFile будет работать в лучшем случае странно.